# function only adds one element to Favorites Array

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I just realized my `markFavorite` function will only add one element to the favorites array, as soon as I try adding another element it will log:

> "FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document
> users/l2c8ieJurAfrqI1Pj6wNWro1S2u2)"

I can keep adding that one element without a problem, but as soon as I try to add another element, I get this error.

Here is the function code:

```js
async function markFavorite(did, nombre, comentarios, valor) {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document.data:", docSnap.data());
      const favoriteUpdate = {
        favorite: true,
        id: did,
        nombre: nombre,
        comentarios: comentarios,
        valor: valor,
      };
      let favoritesUpdate;
      const favorites = docSnap.data().favorites;
     // Checking if the array is empty or not. If it is empty, it will add the new item to the array.
     // If it is not empty, it will check if the item is already in the array. If it is, it will update
     // the item. If it is not, it will add the new item to the array.
      if (favorites && favorites.length) {
        const findAuto = favorites.find((item) => item.id === did);
        if (findAuto) {
          favoritesUpdate = favorites.map((item) =>
            item.id === did ? favoriteUpdate : item
          );
        } else {
          // Adding the new item to the array.
          favoritesUpdate = [...favorites, favoritesUpdate];
        }
      } else {
       // Adding the new item to the array.
        favoritesUpdate = [favoriteUpdate];
      }

      // Updating the document with the new array.
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        favorites: favoritesUpdate,
      });
      alert("¡Añadido a tus favoritos!");
    } else {
      console.log("No se localiza este documento!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

If anybody has a suggestion as to where the problem lies, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be due to a typo:

```
else {
          // Adding the new item to the array.
          favoritesUpdate = [...favorites, favoritesUpdate];
        }
```

it actually has to be :

```js
else {
          // Adding the new item to the array.
          favoritesUpdate = [...favorites, favoriteUpdate];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your function is not getting all arguments it expects.

You have few solutions:

- If functions arguments are all required, then wrap your function
  content in:

  ````
  if(!did && !nombre && !comentarios && !valor){
      // Your function code here   } else {
      console.log('Missing markFavorite function arguments', {...arguments};
      // Could also throw error: throw new Error['Missing arguments']   } } ```
  ````
- Otherwise, if you are ok with these values being empty you can set
  default values in case arguments are empty:

  ```
  async function markFavorite(did = '', nombre = null, comentarios = {}, valor = '') { 
     // Your function code here 
  }
  ```

  Obviously set the default values to match your data model/schema.
- You can also tell Firestore to ignore undefined values, as in not write properties with `undefined` to Firestore, but this should probably be last resort option, as then your data model/schema will not be consistent.

  [Here are data types that work with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

  You would have to initialize firestore like this, with [`ignoreUndefinedProperties`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoresettings#firestoresettingsignoreundefinedproperties) option:

  ```
  import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

  const db = initializeFirestore( app, { ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate your error message. We are getting this kind of error because `favoritesUpdate` declaration doesn't contain any values that's why `favoritesUpdate = [...favorites, favoritesUpdate]` is returned as undefined. One way to fix this, you can use the Firestore provided method `arrayUnion()` as it adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. Your first `else` statement should be like this:

```js
else {
          // Adding the new item to the array.
          favoritesUpdate = arrayUnion(favoriteUpdate);
        }
```

You can check this documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Here's a sample working code for your reference:

```js
async function markFavorite(did, nombre, comentarios, valor) {
    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document.data:", docSnap.data());
        const favoriteUpdate = {
          favorite: true,
          id: did,
          nombre: nombre,
          comentarios: comentarios,
          valor: valor,
        };
        let favoritesUpdate;
        const favorites = docSnap.data().favorites;
       // Checking if the array is empty or not. If it is empty, it will add the new item to the array.
       // If it is not empty, it will check if the item is already in the array. If it is, it will update
       // the item. If it is not, it will add the new item to the array.
        if (favorites && favorites.length) {
          const findAuto = favorites.find((item) => item.id === did);
          if (findAuto) {
            favoritesUpdate = favorites.map((item) =>
              item.id === did ? favoriteUpdate : item
            );
          } else {
            // Adding the new item to the array.
            favoritesUpdate = arrayUnion(favoriteUpdate); //--> This is the one I changed
          }
        } else {
         // You can also use arrayUnion here if there's no data on the document. This will produce the same result.
         // favoritesUpdate = arrayUnion(favoriteUpdate);
         // Adding the new item to the array.
          favoritesUpdate = [favoriteUpdate];
        }
  
        // Updating the document with the new array.
        await updateDoc(docRef, {
          favorites: favoritesUpdate,
        });
        console.log("¡Añadido a tus favoritos!");
      } else {
        console.log("No se localiza este documento!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, it was indeed not receiving the actual value, I was not properly referencing the object, I was passing `favoritesUpdate` and not `favoriteUpdate`.